# How to get the higest number out of the table?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

So I have a table of players which I created in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(PlayerID varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, level int, region varchar(2), name varchar(10));
```

And then with the following values:

```
INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('p001','20', 'eu','phatey');
INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('p002', '15', 'eu', 'hellowz');
INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('p003', '10', 'eu', '3xphhate');
```

Which I don't understand is how to make use of SUM in order to get the highest level of the players(Mostly because I am doing it wrong since I am pretty newbie with this) any suggestion?

Comment: Why would you need sum()? It adds up numbers. Max() returns the highest value.

Comment: Consider using an integer instead of a string for id. It seems to make more sense, and certainly easier to manage.

Comment: ... And a simple ORDER BY... DESC LIMIT 1 will return the highest level

Answer (score 0):

```
 select max(column_name) from table_name;
```

I hope it helps!